# How to put glide-arrows outside of glide-track

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel, glidejs

I`m trying to build a carousel/rondell with glide.js. 
I want the left and right arrows to be displayed outside of the glide-track.
The carousel/rondell should be fully responsive.
Here is a picture of how it should be.
[image: carousel/rondell]

Can somebody help me with that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You have to write the logic for arrows by yourself as Glide only looks for controls inside its root element.

Use a Glide API and the `.go()` method on previously queried HTML elements.

```js
var nextButton = document.querySelector('#next');
var prevButton = document.querySelector('#prev');

var glide = new Glide('#glide');

nextButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  glide.go('>');
})

prevButton.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  glide.go('<');
})

glide.mount();
```

Visit [Glide API documentation](https://glidejs.com/docs/api/) for more informations

Answer (score 0):

You can now customize the buttons by CSS

```js
let glide =new Glider(document.querySelector('.glider'), {
  slidesToShow: 1,
  dots: '#dots',
  draggable: true,
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/glider-js@1/glider.min.js"></script>
<div class="glider-contain">
  <div class="glider">
    <div>your first content here</div>
    <div>your second content here</div>
    <div>your third content here</div>
    <div>your content here</div>
  </div>

  <button aria-label="Previous"  onclick="glide.scrollItem(glide.slide-1)" >«</button>
  <button aria-label="Next" onclick="glide.scrollItem(glide.slide+1)">»</button>
  <div role="tablist" class="dots"></div>
</div>
```